# Extracting string via grep regex assertions

Tags: grep, regular-expression, string

Assume a text string `my_string`

```
$ my_string="foo bar=1ab baz=222;"
```

I would like to extract the alphanumeric string between keyword `baz` and the semi-colon.

How do I have to modify the following grep code using regex assertions to also exclude the trailing semi-colon?

```
$ echo $my_string | grep -oP '(?<='baz=').*'
222;
```

Comment: What should be the outcome for `foo baz=x; bar=y;`? (`x` or `x; bar=y`?). And for `baz=x; baz=y;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the string that you want to extract may itself contain `;`, the simplest thing is probably to replace `.` (which matches any single character) with `[^;]` (which matches any character excluding `;`)

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$my_string" | grep -oP '(?<='baz=')[^;]*'
222
```

With `grep` linked to libpcre 7.2 or newer, you can also simplify the lookbehind using the `\K` form:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$my_string" | grep -oP 'baz=\K[^;]*'
222
```

Those will print all occurrences in the string and assume the matching text doesn't contain newline characters (since `grep` processes each line of input separately).

Answer (score 1):

Steeldriver's answer is accurate, but I have a hard time with lookaheads/behinds and would do it like this for readability (with `bash`):

```
my_string="foo bar=1ab baz=222;"
regex='baz=([0-9]+);'
[[ $my_string =~ $regex ]] &&
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also easy with ***sed***:

```
sed -n 's/.*baz=\([^;]*\).*/\1/p' <<< $my_string
222
```

Answer (score 0):

With any POSIX shell:

- For the text between the first occurrence of `baz=` and the last occurrence of `;` after that:

  ```
  my_string="foo bar=1ab baz=222;"
  case $my_string in
    (*baz=*\;*)
      result=${my_string#*baz=}
      result=${result%;*};;
    (*) result=
  esac
  ```
- for the text between the first occurrence of `baz=` and the next occurrence of `;` after that, replace `%` with `%%` above
- for the *last* occurrence of `baz=`, replace `#` with `##`.